# AgGrid access grid data in a CustomRowRenderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using a AGGrid (actually via custom wrapper) and I have checkoboxes on each row.
Also, I have a bottom row with buttons. I want to enable/disable the buttons based on selected rows.

```
<AgGrid
                        id="dataListGrid"
                        containerProps={{style: {height: gridData.length * 30, minHeight: 180}}}
                        className="customGrid"
                        columnDefs={dataListColumns}
                        frameworkComponents={{checkboxColRenderer: checkboxColRenderer}}
                        gridDescription="List"
                        onGridReady={handleGridReady}
                        rowData={gridData}
                        enableBrowserTooltips={true}
                        pagination
                        paginationPageSize={100}
                        onCellClicked={onCellClicked}
                        onRowSelected={(params) => {
                              params.api.redrawRows({
                                rowNodes: [params.api.getPinnedBottomRow(0)],
                              });
                            }}
                        isFullWidthCell={(rowNode) => rowNode.rowPinned === 'bottom'}
                        fullWidthCellRenderer={CustomPinnedRowRenderer}
                        pinnedBottomRowData={[{}]}
                        {...props}
                    />
```

My data looks like below;

```
let gridData = [{
            fmIdentifier: 'Test data 1',
            category: 'Test',
            comments: 'Test',
            fm: 'Test',
            gti: 'Test data',
            wins: 'Test',
            identifier: 'Test',
            status: 'Test data',
        }, {
            fmIdentifier: 'Test data 2',
            category: 'Test',
            comments: 'Test',
            fm: 'Test',
            gti: 'Test data',
            wins: 'Test',
            identifier: 'Test',
            status: 'Test data X',
            rowPinned: 'bottom'
        }]
        setDataListColumns(DataListColumns);
        setGridData(gridData);
```

Below is how my CustomPinnedRowRenderer looks;

```
class CustomPinnedRowRenderer {
  init(params) {
    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
// QUESTION : I want to access the grid data here...param.api.data shows empty object {}
    const selectedNodes = params.api.getSelectedNodes();
    this.eGui.innerHTML = finalDOMStr; //finalDOMStr has HTML

  }

  getGui() {
    return this.eGui;
  }

  refresh() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

My question is inside the CustomPinnedRowRenderer (on row select), I want to check the param.api.data (so that I can accordingly render enabled/disabled buttons)

But param.api.data seems to be empty object for some reason ?

**UPDATED**

I tried adding the property "checked" to my data model and mapped to checked state as below

```
let gridData = [{
            checked: true,
            fmIdentifier: 'Test data 1',
            category: 'Test',
            comments: 'Test',
            fm: 'Test',
            gti: 'Test data',
            wins: 'Test',
            identifier: 'Test',
            status: 'Test data',
        }, {
            checked: false,
            fmIdentifier: 'Test data 2',
            category: 'Test',
            comments: 'Test',
            fm: 'Test',
            gti: 'Test data',
            wins: 'Test',
            identifier: 'Test',
            status: 'Test data X',
            rowPinned: 'bottom'
        }]
```

However, any checked data stays as checked i.e. I cannot uncheck

My checkboxColRenderer looks as below

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
    return (
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={props.data.checked} />
        </span>
    );
};
```

Comment: Try using `this.params` and `this.params.api.getSelectedeNodes()`

Comment: Thanks...yes, did try that...with that, I just get the currently selected row and not all the selected rows. Not sure why that is the case?

Comment: can you try creating an `array` and storing selected rows `one by one` in the array

Comment: Oh k...you mean like dynamically add the selected rows which I get using this.params.api.getSelectedeNodes()

Comment: yes it could work

Comment: just tried that....but since it gets trigerred for both row select and unselect, I am unable to differentiate between the 2  events

Comment: Do you have id for every row?

Comment: Not really...but I just updated in my original question as to what happens when I try to add checked state to my data model and map to the checkbox

Comment: @DharmikPatel - in case you feel something can be done via id, pls let me know regarding the same...like how I can add id and make use of the same?

Comment: You can add `id` to each row when you are rendering and then if you click on any checkbox then add it to the `array` with the `id`.

Now if someone clicks again on the selected row then you can check in the `array` if the `id` already exists in the `array` and if it does then you can uncheck it and remove it from the `array`.

Comment: It's a little bit complicated but that's the best I can think of right now.

Comment: I think the problem is somehow the call is going to CustomPinnedRowRenderer.init during the initial render and also when I check/uncheck the checkbox

...So not sure where the logic to add/remove ids to array should go

Comment: Can't you create a separate function for that?

Comment: Ok....but how/when do I invoke that function?

Comment: whenever someone clicks the checkbox either to check it or uncheck it